# Microsoft Expression Web 3 clipboard bug

Tags: clipboard, expression-web, microsoft-expression-web, microsoft-expression

There seems to be a rather annoying bug in MS Expression Web 3 (or perhaps an incompatibility with something else I have installed).

Quite often HTML code editor would refuse to copy things into clipboard. You select some text, press Ctrl-C, Ctrl-Insert or use context menu and nothing happens. Then in 10..15 seconds it would start working again... Then again it would not work. It's rather annoying.

Does anyone else have such a problem or knows how to fix it?

I'm running Microsoft Expression Web 3 Service Pack 1 Version 3.0.3813.0 on Windows 7 Ultimate x64 with all latest updates and patches. I have Russian keyboard layout installed. Other than that my system is pretty much plain vanilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now SP2, try using it, maybe it will solve the proplem.

Note : I don't have this proplem

Comment: On the other hand it still happens (maybe not as often)... :(